# How to insert a jcombobox in a jtable row for multiple values

Tags: java, swing, collections

Hashmap contains key and value(result of parsing an XML). Hashmap contains things in the way that key is a string and value is a vector.
A key may have single value in the vector or mutiple values in the vector. 
This hashmap, has to be put into a jtable,such that if the key has single value, put it to text box. If it has multiple values insert a combobox in the table.

You may change the code.

```
hashmap.put(nodeList.item(j).getNodeName(), nodeValueList);
Set keys = PropertyIMPL.hashmap.keySet();
Iterator iteratorKeys = keys.iterator();

while (iteratorKeys.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) iteratorKeys.next();
    if (nodeValueList.size() > 1) {
        tablemodel.insertRow(0, new Object[]{key});
        String[] ss = (String[]) nodeValueList.toArray(
            new String[nodeValueList.size()]);
        TableColumn col = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
        col.setCellEditor(new MyComboBoxEditor(ss));
    } else {
        tablemodel.insertRow(0, new Object[]{key, nodeValueList});
    }
}

keys.clear();
```

Comment: accept some of the answers to your questions. Plus make clearly a statement of what is the problem in each question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is you need to override the getCellEditor(...) method of JTable.