# How to store multiple values in a JTable row as a JCombobox

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, tablecelleditor

Hashmap contains key and value(result of parsing an XML). Hashmap contains things in the way that key is a string and value is a vector. A key may have single value in the vector or mutiple values in the vector.

My question is:

This hashmap, has to be put into a jtable,such that if the key has single value, put it to text box. If it has multiple values insert a combobox in the row of that table.

I need the swing code for this problem

Comment: exact duplicate of [How to insert a jcombobox in a jtable row for multiple values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026474/how-to-insert-a-jcombobox-in-a-jtable-row-for-multiple-values) (except for - the last question contained some code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not code but steps that can help you..

1. Create a Table.
2. Every time adding a new row check for the hashmap value and if it is a single value add textbox to that cell or add comboBox.
3. Repeat step 2 for all hashmap keys.

References that can help you:-

1. [Adding row in table](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/InsertarowtoatablethroughDefaultTableModel.htm)
2. [Adding comboBox in table](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ComboBoxTable.htm)
3. [JTable add/remove rows to custom table model (updating table display)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494276/jtable-add-remove-rows-to-custom-table-model-updating-table-display)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a HashMap<String, Vector<ValueType>> which maps a String key to a Vector. In this case, even a single value will be stored in a Vector, and when you add the first element for a hash key, you have to make a vector, add the element to it, and put the vector with the key. Subsequently you can just add to the vector. For display, determine if the Vector has 1 or more elements to decide which UI to use.